# Fine-Uploader upload order for multi-file uploads?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I am using fine uploader for multiple file uploads to my server. I need the files to be uploaded in a certain order but i cant figure out how to sort the order that the files are uploaded. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

The order in which files are uploaded can be influenced by a number of different variables, as there are a few different async tasks involved before actually sending the file. You could try to limit the `maxConnections` option to `1`, but I can't guarantee this will always result in the files being sent in the order you select them. Your best bet is to simply *not* depend on any specific order. In other words, consider adjusting your server-side code to store the files and then react appropriately once the files it needs are available.

Comment: I would change my server side logic but the code that is breaking is in a .dll and i do not have access to that code. I really need to force certain file types (.dtsx) to be uploaded first, before .dtproj, .conmgr, .database, etc.

Comment: Your best bet is to accept the files from users via your own code, and then feed them into [Fine Uploader's `addFiles` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles) in the preferred order.